# Axios post request with proxy isn't working

Tags: node.js, proxy, axios

*Without the proxy it works*

I have never worked with proxies before so I don't know what I should look out for... but  _currentURL: http://[proxy]/pathToPayments seems to be looking weird. I have no clue on what is happening though.

```js
app.get('/payment', (req, res) => {
  const amount = req.body;

  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('ssl_merchant_id', MERCHANTID);
  params.append('ssl_user_id', MERCHANTUSERID);
  params.append('ssl_pin', MERCHANTPIN);
  params.append('ssl_transaction_type', 'ccsale');
  params.append('ssl_amount', 150);

  let axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    proxy: {
      host: FIXIE_URL,
      port: 80,
    },
  };

  axios
    .post(
      'https://api.demo.convergepay.com/hosted-payments/transaction_token',
      params,
      axiosConfig,
    )
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .then((token) => {
      console.log(token);
      res.redirect(
        `https://api.demo.convergepay.com/hosted-payments?ssl_txn_auth_token=${token}`,
      );
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Need more explanation about what you are trying to achieve and what the actual result.

Comment: I want the user to be able to click on a link and be directed to a hosted payments page. I have to use a proxy due to Heroku changing IPs and this payments site needing to whitelist IPs. Fixie is an add on that Heroku uses for this. Their docs are deprecated (using response package) so I need to use axios. Right now link is clicked and it just loads forever and the images shows what I get. Taking proxy object out of axiosConfig makes it work on localhost but I need the proxy to work.

Answer (score 2):

I emailed Fixie about this. They ended up updating their docs with axios information due to what they had been using being deprecated.

"Specifically, what's wrong in the pasted code is that you the host is wrong (you just need to provide the hostname, not the full url), and you need to provide the auth credentials. So something like this:

```js
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://example.com',
  proxy: {
    protocol: 'http',
    host: YOUR_FIXIE_HOST,
    port: 80,
    auth: {
      username: 'fixie',
      password: FIXIE_TOKEN
    }
  }
})
  .then(function (response) {
    // Do something with the response
  });
```

Your fixie host is a fixie subdomain, without any protocol or port information. So something like triathalon.usefixie.com. Your fixie token is the random string after `fixie:` in the full fixie url."